# Reading pages of 2 or more columns using OCR

Tags: ocr, wikipedia

I used Google-OCR built-in tool from wikisource and it worked as expected. But if there are 2 columns on a page - when I OCR text, it gets mixed up.
For e.g.

https://archive.org/details/TagorechiGoshti-Marathi/page/n21/mode/2up

This page has 2 columns each per page. The text from second column is printed next to text from first column which is wrong.
How do I load this file in wiksource?

---

Update:

It works correctly on english wikisource. For e.g. The first line is correct on this page...

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Harper%27s_New_Monthly_Magazine_-_v109.djvu/416

I thought it would read something like this:

> watched him with the look of one at to Rohan, and touched the glass
> first

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the response you receive from API. There is a field Bounding Polygon and you should be able to use coordinates to parse text the way you need.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/a0b69c84ebc00c54c94d

Comment: https://github.com/neqkir/wikisource-scraper